# number of maxima, minima, and saddle points on a Grassmannian

Tags: grassmannians

I have a positive, smooth function on a Grassmannian. I am wondering whether there exists any relation between the numbers of maxima, minima, and saddle points. At least on a 2-sphere, we have the Euler relation, namely, the number of maxima plus the the number of minima minus the number of saddle points equals 2.

Comment: It's called Morse theory.  Or you can look up Poincare-Hopf theorem.